# Why is my phone simulating a wider screen resulution

Tags: android, html, ios, css, screen-resolution

The resulution width of the phone is 375px.

The phone shows a page of an app and it has a width of 980px.

[image]

This creates a zoom out effect making everything on the page smaller than it should be.

See screenshot from desktop-chrome with the iPhone 6 device turned on. It looks the same on the real device and on android etc.

Other pages work as expected.

Could be related to css.

Comment: need code, try setting width to 100vw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you forgot to set your meta viewport tag (to this):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: This is the solution. Thank you!